Debian 12/Proxmox 8 - apacheds.service - Apache Directory Server - error on start after clean install...?
there is a Proxmox 8 installed manually on clean Debian 12 (packages up to date).
We want to run a basic LDAP for numer of apps thus there was an idea to deploy it directly on host and I've executed a basic command:
apt-get install apacheds

It also installed some additional dependencies with default-jre-headless as well.
However apacheds was not starting due to error:
systemctl status apacheds
× apacheds.service - Apache Directory Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apacheds.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2024-05-20 22:02:06 CEST; 1min 20s ago
   Duration: 134ms
    Process: 351775 ExecStart=/bin/sh -c exec              ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java ${JAVA_OPTS}                -Dapacheds.controls=${ADS_CONTROLS}               >
   Main PID: 351775 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 20 22:02:06 lab30 systemd[1]: Started apacheds.service - Apache Directory Server.
May 20 22:02:06 lab30 sh[351775]: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
May 20 22:02:06 lab30 sh[351775]:         at org.apache.directory.server.UberjarMain.<clinit>(UberjarMain.java:48)
May 20 22:02:06 lab30 sh[351775]: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
May 20 22:02:06 lab30 sh[351775]:         at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
May 20 22:02:06 lab30 sh[351775]:         at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
May 20 22:02:06 lab30 sh[351775]:         at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
May 20 22:02:06 lab30 sh[351775]:         ... 1 more
May 20 22:02:06 lab30 systemd[1]: apacheds.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 20 22:02:06 lab30 systemd[1]: apacheds.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

After that I've manually installed the full JRE with command:
apt-get install default-jre
and also manually exported the system-wide:
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java
But apacheds error stays the same and LDAP is not even starting. Nor any other idea so far didn't help resolved the apacheds starting problem and honestly speaking I don't know what to do next while this is all on original packages from built-in repositories and that should work right after installation out of the box and it's a bit suprising that we're having such issues nowadays on Debian 12.
Could you please help me with resolving the issue and making the basic LDAP from apacheds running under Debian 12/Proxmox 8?
Cheers,
K.

I'm a great fan of Debian and a long time user. I run virtually nothing else. But there is something know as 'Debianbork' in some circles (looking at you Apache httpd). That package looks really weird. It's full of jar 'files' that are actually symlinks to one 'uber' jar (shown in your exception). You need to investigate via the package maintainer. In the meantime it won't hurt to download the tar from the site, unpack it and run java -jar apacheds-2.0.0.AM28-SNAPSHOT/lib/apacheds-service-2.0.0.AM28-SNAPSHOT.jar default start That's it - running!

If you're feeling adventurous, stop the service (until it's working, you need to either disable it or uninstall it) back up the service file apacheds.service and replace lines 18 and 19 with -jar /usr/share/java/apacheds-service.jar \ Restart the service. It might then work (I haven't tried it) (I failed to mark up that second code btw, so be careful about that terminating backslash)

thank you, I know that generic package from - https://directory.apache.org/apacheds/download/download-linux-deb.html - starts fine - however it's not from repository so there will be no automatic patches/upgrades with apt and what's it actually doesn't integrate with systemd to much out-of-the-box, so yes, I've even already deployed it and starting/stopping it via /etc/init.d-script as an workaround, but the question is why the original Debian12 apacheds package is fundamentally broken in the distro itself and how to fix it permanently in order to have running from the repos with updates, etc.

the second idea I will try in next days while today I need to catch some sleep ;-)

My guess - the package maintainer is not much of a Java person. But I could be totally wrong. Try my fix and report to the maintainer if it works. The real thing shouldn't have hard-coded (literal) jar file name though

Of course it must be said that we can't jump to the conclusion that the package is broken as such. It might be that it's a quirk of your system or a problem with installation. There are things that are weird about the package but that can be discussed later maybe

This question is probably a better fit for [unix.se]
